# WP text editor change html markup

Tags: posts

i use markup:

```
<div class="owl-carousel-wrap photo-gallery ">
  <div id="photoGallery" class="owl-carousel ">
   <a href="#galleryPhotos"  data-slide-to="0"><div class="item " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#photoGalleryModal">
     <div class="photo-gallery_item"><img class="alignnone size-large wp-image-479" src="http://site/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/slide_6-comp-1024x683.jpg" alt="" /></div></div></a>
   <a href="#galleryPhotos"  data-slide-to="1"><div class="item " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#photoGalleryModal">
     <div class="photo-gallery_item"><img class="alignnone size-large wp-image-480" src="http://site/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/slide_7-comp-1024x683.jpg" alt="" /></div></div></a>
  <div>
</div>
```

when i paste this code into wp text editor, its remove tags `a`, and i have this:

```
<div class="owl-carousel-wrap photo-gallery ">
   <div id="photoGallery" class="owl-carousel ">
     <div class="item " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#photoGalleryModal">
       <div class="photo-gallery_item"><img class="alignnone size-large wp-image-479" src="http://site/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/slide_6-comp-1024x683.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#photoGalleryModal">
       <div class="photo-gallery_item"><img class="alignnone size-large wp-image-480" src="http://site/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/slide_7-comp-1024x683.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WP is removing things like `data-slide-to="0'` because it thinks it's cleaning up your HTML for you. Whenever you have somewhat custom HTML like this, use a shortcode instead. You happen to be in luck - there's already a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/owl-carousel/) that creates the shortcode for you.

If you don't want to use a plugin, and you are using a custom theme or a custom child theme already, you could review the code in the plugin and build something similar into your theme.

Comment: i add html pages to wp. i use plugin TinyMCE Advanced, but its not work how i expect. i cant "build something similar into your theme" i'm beginner, and i dont know php

Comment: So, it sounds like simply using the plugin recommended would solve your issue. Use shortcodes instead of trying to add complex HTML directly into the WP Editor. It will always strip away things it deems unnecessary.

Comment: thank you for advice, but i need use text editor for static page

Comment: Using the recommended plugin will let you use the text editor. You just paste in a shortcode instead of the full HTML. WP won't let you paste your full desired HTML straight into the text editor. It will always filter out required elements.